# how to solve the IndexError: too many indices for array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, regression, mnist

Hello I am building the Softmax Regression however I have got error
first I needed to extract the gzip mnist file than to convert them that it can work 
but I got problem with the array size for the label datasets training

I am not sure is the problem because the extracting does not works well or because there is problem in the indices

the error says
batch_labels = TrainlableData[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]

IndexError: too many indices for array

how this can be solved?

```
import numpy as np
#import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import struct as st
from array import array
#using struct to handel the binary files
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
import idx2numpy
from skimage import img_as_float
from skimage import img_as_float32

import gzip

print(tf.__version__)



# number of features 
num_features = 784
# number of target labels 
num_labels = 10
# learning rate (alpha) 
learning_rate = 0.05
# batch size 
batch_size = 128
# number of epochs 
num_steps = 5001

with gzip.open('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz','rb') as f:
     magicTrainImage = st.unpack('>4B',f.read(4))
     trainImg = st.unpack('>I',f.read(4))[0] #num of images
     trainImgnRow = st.unpack('>I',f.read(4))[0] #num of rows
     trainImgnC = st.unpack('>I',f.read(4))[0] #num of column
     nBytesTotal = trainImg*trainImgnRow*trainImgnC*1 #since each pixel data is 1 byte
     trainImagesData = 255 - np.asarray(st.unpack('>'+'B'*nBytesTotal,f.read(nBytesTotal))).reshape((trainImg,trainImgnRow*trainImgnC))

print(trainImg)

with gzip.open('train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz','rb') as S:
    magic, size = st.unpack(">II",S.read(8))
    TrainlableData = np.asarray(array("B", S.read()))
print("lable data ")
print(TrainlableData.shape)


with gzip.open('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz','rb') as f:
     magicTrainImage = st.unpack('>4B',f.read(4))
     trainImg = st.unpack('>I',f.read(4))[0] #num of images
     trainImgnRow = st.unpack('>I',f.read(4))[0] #num of rows
     trainImgnC = st.unpack('>I',f.read(4))[0] #num of column
     nBytesTotal = trainImg*trainImgnRow*trainImgnC*1 #since each pixel data is 1 byte
     TestImageData = 255 - np.asarray(st.unpack('>'+'B'*nBytesTotal,f.read(nBytesTotal))).reshape((trainImg,trainImgnRow*trainImgnC))

print(TestImageData.shape)


with gzip.open('t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz','rb') as S:
    magic, size = st.unpack(">II",S.read(8))
    TestlableData = np.asarray(array("B", S.read()))

print(TestlableData.shape)

td = img_as_float32(TestImageData)

print(td.dtype)

# initialize a tensorflow graph 
graph = tf.Graph() 

with graph.as_default(): 
    """ 
    defining all the nodes 
    """

    # Inputs 
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_features)) 
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels)) 
    #tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset) 
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(td) 


    # Variables. 
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_features, num_labels])) 
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels])) 

    # Training computation. 
    logits = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights) + biases 
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits( 
                        labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits)) 

    # Optimizer. 
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss) 

    # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data. 
    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits) 
    #valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights) + biases) 
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights) + biases) 




# utility function to calculate accuracy 
def accuracy(predictions, labels): 
    correctly_predicted = np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1)) 
    accu = (100.0 * correctly_predicted) / predictions.shape[0] 
    return accu 

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session: 
    # initialize weights and biases 
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run() 
    print("Initialized") 

    for step in range(num_steps): 
        # pick a randomized offset 
        offset = np.random.randint(0, TrainlableData.shape[0] - batch_size - 1) 

        # Generate a minibatch. 
        batch_data = trainImagesData[offset:(offset + batch_size), :] 
        batch_labels = TrainlableData[offset:(offset + batch_size), :] 

        print(batch_data.shape)
        print(batch_labels.shape)

        # Prepare the feed dict 
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, 
                     tf_train_labels : batch_labels} 

        # run one step of computation 
        _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], 
                                        feed_dict=feed_dict) 

        if (step % 500 == 0): 
            print("Minibatch loss at step {0}: {1}".format(step, l)) 
            print("Minibatch accuracy: {:.1f}%".format( 
                accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))) 


    print("\nTest accuracy: {:.1f}%".format( 
        accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), TestlableData)))
```

Comment: What is the result of `print(TrainlableData.shape)` ? I suspect `TrainlableData` is a 1D array so you should use `TrainlableData[offset:(offset + batch_size)]` instead of `TrainlableData[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]`

Comment: doing that causes another problem ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (128,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(128, 10)'  feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, 
                     tf_train_labels : batch_labels}  That is why I thought may be the problem is in the extracting the label data